# Bad SSL handshake from Jersey

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly

Given this Jersey init code:

```
    boolean clientMode = false,
            needClientAuth = true,
            wantClientAuth = true;
    SSLContext sslcconf = SSLContext.getDefault();
    SSLEngineConfigurator ssleconf = new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslcconf, clientMode, needClientAuth, wantClientAuth);
    boolean secure = true,
            start = true;
    ResourceConfig resconf = new ResourceConfig(classes);
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        new URI("https://localhost:8080"),
        resconf, secure, ssleconf, start);
```

All client that attempt to connect to this server throw generic SSL handshake errors. In particular:

```
$ openssl s_client -debug -msg -connect localhost:8080
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0xa024118 [0xa024b48] (118 bytes => 118 (0x76))
0000 - 80 74 01 03 01 00 4b 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   .t....K... ..9..
0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00   ..3..2../.......
0030 - 00 04 01 00 80 00 00 15-00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00   ................
0040 - 40 00 00 14 00 00 11 00-00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80   @...............
0050 - 00 00 03 02 00 80 bf 3e-48 68 ef c9 6f aa 65 88   .......>Hh..o.e.
0060 - 86 e7 eb 77 e9 be 3c 69-67 0b 3c ae 3a dc 69 5f   ...w..<ig.<.:.i_
0070 - ad c0 c4 93 61 ce                                 ....a.
>>> SSL 2.0 [length 0074], CLIENT-HELLO
    01 03 01 00 4b 00 00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00 38 00
    00 35 00 00 16 00 00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0 00 00
    33 00 00 32 00 00 2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00 00 04
    01 00 80 00 00 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00 40 00
    00 14 00 00 11 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80 00 00
    03 02 00 80 bf 3e 48 68 ef c9 6f aa 65 88 86 e7
    eb 77 e9 be 3c 69 67 0b 3c ae 3a dc 69 5f ad c0
    c4 93 61 ce
read from 0xa024118 [0xa02a0a8] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
21856:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

Compare this with a good request to a different server:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0xa024138 [0xa024b48] (118 bytes => 118 (0x76))
0000 - 80 74 01 03 01 00 4b 00-00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00   .t....K... ..9..
0010 - 38 00 00 35 00 00 16 00-00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0   8..5............
0020 - 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00-2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00   ..3..2../.......
0030 - 00 04 01 00 80 00 00 15-00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00   ................
0040 - 40 00 00 14 00 00 11 00-00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80   @...............
0050 - 00 00 03 02 00 80 b1 33-32 65 f0 53 60 2d aa 85   .......32e.S`-..
0060 - b1 5c 19 1f f2 5b 8b 1a-2d 8a ed 8f c0 79 f7 72   .\...[..-....y.r
0070 - 9c 31 b3 ec 39 b5                                 .1..9.
>>> SSL 2.0 [length 0074], CLIENT-HELLO
    01 03 01 00 4b 00 00 00 20 00 00 39 00 00 38 00
    00 35 00 00 16 00 00 13 00 00 0a 07 00 c0 00 00
    33 00 00 32 00 00 2f 03 00 80 00 00 05 00 00 04
    01 00 80 00 00 15 00 00 12 00 00 09 06 00 40 00
    00 14 00 00 11 00 00 08 00 00 06 04 00 80 00 00
    03 02 00 80 b1 33 32 65 f0 53 60 2d aa 85 b1 5c
    19 1f f2 5b 8b 1a 2d 8a ed 8f c0 79 f7 72 9c 31
    b3 ec 39 b5
read from 0xa024138 [0xa02a0a8] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 4a 02                                 ....J.
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
...
```

Edit: The following produces similar results despite explicit ciphers:

```
    boolean clientMode = false,
            needClientAuth = true,
            wantClientAuth = true;
    SSLContextConfigurator sslcconf = new SSLContextConfigurator();
    sslcconf.setSecurityProtocol("TLSv1.2");
    SSLEngineConfigurator ssleconf = new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslcconf, clientMode, needClientAuth, wantClientAuth);
    ssleconf.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2" });
    ssleconf.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
    });

    // SSLContext sslcconf = SSLContext.getDefault();
    boolean secure = true,
            start = true;
    ResourceConfig resconf = new ResourceConfig(classes);
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        new URI("https://localhost:8080"),
        resconf, secure, ssleconf, start);
```

Comment: try using the -ssl2 option in the s_client. If that works, you should know that sslv2 has many many issues.

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks like an OpenSSL issue. Did the server you are connecting to disable SSLv3?
You need to check the version of OpenSSL running on that client. If you have the 0.9.x branch installed, the default context does not include TLS, even though the library can support TLS. In the code you posted above, it is defaulting to the default context, rather than you specifying your own, so in this scenario, with SSLv3 disabled on the remote, you won't be able to connect.

You have a few options here if this is true:

1. enable SSLv3 on the remote (Do NOT do this)
2. update to the 1.x openssl branch on your client which should have a more modern default context
3. change your code to modify your context and explicitly define your cipher string.

Comment: I have added the cipher list explicitly but it doesn't seem to have changed the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for strange question, but did you configure Keystore (with proper password and so on) for SSLContextConfigurator ?

If you forget to do this or key cant't be obtained from keystore (due to misconfiguration or error), "SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL" will be used as cipher and then you will get "no cipher suites in common" and failed handshake.